# Why is 'gedit' going back to default tab sizes all the time?

Tags: gedit

Everytime I open a file in gedit, I have to change again the tab with from 8 to 4, as I prefer it.

Is there any configuration file where I can make 4 the default tab width?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In `gedit`'s menu, go to Edit -> Preferences. When the "gedit Preferences" window pops up, click on the "Editor" tab, and you'll be able to change the Tab Width setting.

Comment: This does not apply to the latest versions of Gedit with GNOME 3.

Comment: @Flimm: In Gedit in Gnome 3, you can find the preferences dialog by clicking on the top bar of the screen, next to "Activities".

Comment: @RaoulSteffen I don't think there's a Tab Width setting though.

Comment: @Flimm: There is for me. Menu > Preferences > Editor > Tab Stops > Tab width. Looks much like the screenshot jrg posted in his answer.
I have got Gedit 3.28.1 (as it came with Ubuntu 18.04).

Answer (score 12):

For GNOME 3, [go here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030624/6005)

### GNOME 2

Go to `Edit > Preferences` in gedit. Then, switch to the `Editor` tab:

[image]

Edit those preferences to your hearts content.

*(Please excuse the ugly GTK theme, the latest Oneiric updates broke my XFCE themes)*

Comment: This does not apply with the latest versions of Gedit in GNOME 3.

Answer (score 9):

Open Terminal and type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor tabs-size 4
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer works in the latest version of Gedit in GNOME 3.

Comment: Also you need this if you want to edit Python scripts:


`gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor insert-spaces true`


It tells `gedit` to use spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: I found the `insert-spaces` with `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor | grep space`.

Comment: For auto indentation: `gsettings org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor auto-indent true`